# How to darken texture of sprite node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code where I create a sprite node that displays an animated GIF. I want to create another function that darkens the GIF when called upon. I could still be able to watch the animation, but the content would be visibly darker. I'm not sure how to approach this. Should I individually darken every texture or frame used to create the animation? If so, how do I darken a texture or frame in the first place?

```
    // Extract frames and duration
    guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url as URL) else {
        return 
    }
    let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)
    var images = [CGImage]()
    let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source!)
    var delays = [Int]()
    // Fill arrays
    for i in 0..<count {
        // Add image
        if let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source!, i, nil) {
            images.append(image)
        }

        // At it's delay in cs
        let delaySeconds = UIImage.delayForImageAtIndex(Int(i),
                                                        source: source)
        delays.append(Int(delaySeconds * 1000.0)) // Seconds to ms
    }

    // Calculate full duration
    let duration: Int = {
        var sum = 0

        for val: Int in delays {
            sum += val
        }

        return sum
    }()

    // Get frames
    let gcd = SKScene.gcdForArray(delays)
    var frames = [SKTexture]()

    var frame: SKTexture
    var frameCount: Int
    for i in 0..<count {
        frame = SKTexture(cgImage: images[Int(i)])
        frameCount = Int(delays[Int(i)] / gcd)

        for _ in 0..<frameCount {
            frames.append(frame)
        }
    }


    let gifNode = SKSpriteNode.init(texture: frames[0])
    gifNode.position = CGPoint(x: skScene.size.width / 2.0, y: skScene.size.height / 2.0)
    gifNode.name = "content"


    // Add animation 
    let gifAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: frames, timePerFrame: ((Double(duration) / 1000.0)) / Double(frames.count))
    gifNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(gifAnimation))
    skScene.addChild(gifNode)
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the `colorize(with:colorBlendFactor:duration:)` method. It is an SKAction that animates changing the color of a whole node. That way you don't have to get into darkening the individual textures or frames, and it also adds a nice transition from a non-dark to a darkened color. Once the action ends, the node will stay darkened until you undarken it, so any changes to the node's texture will also be visible as darkend to the user.

Choose whatever color and colorBlendFactor will work best for you to have the darkened effect you need, e.g. you could set the `color` to `.black` and `colorBlendFactor` to 0.3. To undarken, just set the color to `.clear` and `colorBlendFactor` to 0.

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417678-colorize).

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked! However, `.clear` doesn't seem to undarken the image. Any other suggestions for undarkening?

Comment: Solved it. Just change the colorBlendFactor to 0 and reapply the `SKAction` to remove the filter.

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot to add that you should set the colorBlendFator to 0 to undarken. Thanks! I edited the answer now.